# Is there a meaning to the equation $c_1(E,h)=\lambda \omega$?

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a Kahler manifold and $(E,h)\to X$ a Hermitian holomorphic vector bundle on $X$. Denote by $c_1(E,h)\in \Omega^{1,1}(X)$ the first Chern form of $E$ with respect to the metric $h$. In other words $c_1(E,h)=\operatorname{Tr}(\frac{i}{2\pi}F_h)$.

Is there any meaning to the equation (on the metric $h$)
$$c_1(E,h) = \lambda \omega$$
or the equation
$$c_1(E,h)\wedge \omega^{n-1} = \lambda \omega^n$$
for a constant $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$? That equation is the trace of the Hermitian-Einstein equation but I wonder whether there are any applications or properties to it.

Comment: For $\lambda > 0$ (respect $\lambda < 0$) the first equation equivelant to $E$ being ample (respect anti ample). That is the Kodaira embedding theorem, When $\lambda = 0$ it is equivelant the condition that $c_{1}(E)=0$. For the second equation the conclusions won't be nearly as strong, since the product with $\omega ^{n-1}$ has a kernel which is at least a hyperplane in $H^{2}$ adding anything in the kernel won't change the equation.

Comment: @NickL Being (anti)-ample is a topological characterization of $E$, which is related to the existence of such metric. I am interested in the equation on $h$ itself

Comment: Btw I am not sure you are right, being ample is related to the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_E(1)\to \mathbb{P}E$